# Логирование и Мониторинг микросервисов на группах серверов

Tags: логирование, devops, микросервисы, мониторинг

У меня есть проект с двумя группами виртуальных серверов (*серверы в каждой группе просто копии одного образа с одинаковыми наборами микросервисов, как поды в k8s*), балансировщиком и парой VPS с БД. Сейчас Docker и K8S пока не используются в виду небольшого масштаба проекта (однако есть в планах). Вместо этого, используются возможности нашего облачного провайдера: управление дисковыми образами, виртуалками и их группами с автоматическим созданием/удалением в зависимости от нагрузки. На данный момент это работает хорошо, но есть недостаток централизованного логирования и мониторинга, я постарался выделить следующие потребности:

1. Дашборд с параметрами серверов вроде использования CPU, RAM, дискового места, сети и т.д. для каждого сервера. Некоторые дашборды доступны от нашего провайдера, есть крутые консольные утилиты, но хотелось бы иметь независимое и централизованное решение.
2. Дашборд с числом ответов по разным HTTP кодам, как для каждой группы серверов в целом, так и для каждого сервера отдельно. Мы используем NginX и он предоставляет страницу со статусом, но это работает только по отдельным серверам (и опять же, нужна централизация).
3. Окно для анализа логов с поддержкой многострочных сообщений (вроде трейсбеков);
4. Независимость от языка программирования и стека технологий.
5. Возможность задать уведомления по почте (а ещё лучше с запускать консольного скрипта, чтобы послать уведомление в Тг) с кастомными триггерами на метрики.
6. Возможно есть какие-то другие важные фичи?

Дополнительные пожелания:

7. Решение должно быть бесплатным.
8. Также желательна простота в настройке. Надеюсь, что какое-то одно решение может быть достаточно гибким, чтобы покрыть все описанные нужды логирования и мониторинга.
9. Зреслость / популярность решения, доступность документации и примеров.
10. Решение должно сохраниться с минимальными изменениями, когда придёт время миграции в контейнеры.

На мой взгляд, итоговое решение выглядит следующим образом: 1) сервер, который сохраняет логи и рассчитывает метрики, предоставляет дашборды и инструменты для анализа логов, и 2) скрипт, установленный на каждом сервере, который запускается по таймеру и периодически отправляет локальные логи на сервер. Однако: как скрипт узнает, какие логи надо искать и отправлять на конкретном сервере, используя конфиг? Но возможно я ошибаюсь насчёт этого алгоритма работы.

В сети есть тонны рекомендаций по LogStash, ElasticSearch, Grafana, Kibana, Zabbix, Loki, Prometheus и т.д, но они почти не описывают отличия разных решений и их фич, не дают понимания, в каких случаях и почему лучше использовать то или иное решение. Я хотел бы увидеть современное объяснение, какое ПО может быть использовано друг с другом, каким образом и когда, а также сравнение в призме описанных потребностей.
Также я надеюсь, что ответы будут полезны многим другим разработчикам, так как тема очень актуальна и полезна в наше время `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, после часов изучения статей и документации, я во всём разобрался Сравнительная таблица:

[image: Логирование и Мониторинг сереро by AivanF]

---

**Zabbix** это полнофункциональная технология которая работает и с метриками, и с логами, при этом расширяема. Также поддерживает автоматическое обнаружение хостов и построение карты сети.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Оф.сайт ZABBIX](https://www.zabbix.com/ru)
- Хабр: [Zabbix: мониторим всё подряд](https://habr.com/ru/post/485538/)

---

**Prometheus** Это система мониторинга метрик. Создан для микросервисов и Kubernetes, может автоматически обнаруживать хосты для выгрузки данных. Имеет массу поддерживаемых адаптеров: [docs: Exporters and Integrations](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/). Для визуализации данных используется Grafana. Касательно хранения данных, Прометей имеет собственную систему для локального хранения, но имеются интеграции со сторонними технологиями для шардирования, см. [docs: Storage](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/).

Полезные ссылки:

- [Оф.сайт Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)
- Хабр: [Мониторинг с Prometheus в Kubernetes](https://habr.com/en/company/flant/blog/340728/)
- Хабр: [Полное руководство по Prometheus в 2019](https://habr.com/en/company/southbridge/blog/455290/)
- Хабр: [Хранилище данных для Prometheus: Thanos vs VictoriaMetrics](https://habr.com/ru/post/482272/)
- Хабр: [Thanos — масштабируемый Prometheus](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/502122/)

---

**PLG** это стэк для обработки логов вдохновлённый Прометеем. Логи собираются через PromTail, а **Loki** это центральный компонент обработки. Также используется Grafana в качестве интерфейса. Локи не имеет своей системы хранения, поэтому требуются сторонние решения. Локи хранит данные в виде чанков и индексов, которые обычно хранятся отдельно, подробнее в [docs: Storage](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/). Как я понял, стэк PLG не имеет системы триггеров/уведомлеений, но компонент извлечения логов также может парсить их в метрики и отправлять в Прометей, таим образом получаются алерты. Также я заметил, что PromTail [не поддерживает многострочные логи](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/74), но вместо него можно использовать более гибкий FluentD.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Оф.сайт Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/)
- Хабр: [EFK vs PLG](https://habr.com/en/company/southbridge/blog/510822/)
- Хабр: [Собираем логи с Loki](https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/507718/)
- Хабр: [Loki — сбор логов, используя подход Prometheus](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/487118/)

---

**ELK / EFK** это традиционный стэк для парсинга, индексирования и поиска логов, может производить сложные запросы. Для извлечения данных изначально использовался LogStash, но FluentD становится более популярным.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Оф.сайт Elastic Stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack)
- Хабр: [EFK vs PLG](https://habr.com/en/company/southbridge/blog/510822/)

Comment: В вашей таблице написано, что ElasticSearch не умеет Metrics. Вы неправы - для метрик у Эластика есть MetricBeat. Пользуюсь уже около года на не очень нагруженном проекте - полёт нормальный, хотя есть сомнения, что оно будет хорошо скэйлиться для больших проектов. Хотя может быть...

Comment: @Slavik спасибо за инфу! Это и логично в принципе, ничего не мешает создать такой инструмент. Надо будет обновить табличку.

Comment: С точки зрения сбора логов могу порекомендовать Fluent Bit (преемник Fluentd, но более легковесный). Он подходит под все сценарии использования: как агент на сервере, как агент в поде и для удаленного логирования. Советую ознакомиться с подходами в cluster-level логировании поподробнее, перед тем, как разворачивать свое решение: https://www.influunt.ru/kubernetes-cluster-level-logging-intro